# How can I prove that $|\sqrt[x]{a}-\sqrt[x]{b}| \leq |\sqrt[x]{a-b}|$

Tags: analysis, inequality

How can I prove that $$|\sqrt[x]{a}-\sqrt[x]{b}| \leq |\sqrt[x]{a-b}|$$
for any $x>1$ and $a,b >0$. Is there a name for this result?

Answer (score 0):

First off, we want $a>b$, else defining $\sqrt[x]{a-b}$ is quite problematic.  Hence the inequality becomes $$\sqrt[x]{a}\le \sqrt[x]{b}+\sqrt[x]{a-b}$$
Now set $c=a-b$ and we get $$\sqrt[x]{c+b}\le \sqrt[x]{b}+\sqrt[x]{c}$$

Now, the property being described is called [subadditivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity), which indeed all functions $\sqrt[x]{\cdot}$ possess, provided $x\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If we set $a=u^x,b=v^x$ we are stating that:
$$ \left(v^x - u^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\geq (v-u) \tag{1}$$
as soon as $v>u>0$. The inequality is homogeneous, hence we may assume $u=1$ without loss of generality, then set $v=(1+z)$ with $z>0$ and prove that:
$$\forall x\geq 1,z>0,\qquad  (1+z)^x \geq z^x + 1.\tag{2} $$
That follows from:
$$ (1+z)^x-z^x = \int_{z}^{z+1} x y^{x-1}\,dy \geq \int_{z}^{z+1} x\,dy \geq \int_{z}^{z+1} 1\,dy = 1.\tag{3}$$